# Django Admin Theming

Tags: python, django

My Django admin dashboard is loading with a dark theme. I don't have any extensions for dark themes installed into my browser. How can I revert it to the light theme? Currently, my admin area is in this state:

[django admin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9dZw.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 11):

As of Django 3.2, there is [dark theme support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#theming-support) which respects the system preference.
Since your system is set to dark mode, it uses the dark theme for the admin. Most people would consider this to be a good thing as users that are used to dark don't get the light theme site, and vice versa.

If you'd still want to change it you can add a **admin/base.html** template override to your project:

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}

{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<style>
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --primary: #79aec8;
    --primary-fg: #fff;

    --body-fg: #333;
    --body-bg: #fff;
    --body-quiet-color: #666;
    --body-loud-color: #000;

    --breadcrumbs-link-fg: var(--body-bg);
    --breadcrumbs-bg: var(--primary);

    --link-fg: #447e9b;
    --link-hover-color: #036;
    --link-selected-fg: #5b80b2;

    --hairline-color: #e8e8e8;
    --border-color: #ccc;

    --error-fg: #ba2121;      
    --message-success-bg: #dfd;
    --message-warning-bg: #ffc;
    --message-error-bg: #ffefef;

    --darkened-bg: #f8f8f8;
    --selected-bg: #e4e4e4;
    --selected-row: #ffc;

    --close-button-bg: #888;
    --close-button-hover-bg: #747474;
  }
}
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

It is essentially the same as putting the default color inside the dark theme as well (would be better to just remove the dark theme colors but I don't think you can). The CSS was taken from [Django's source code on GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css). Refer to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#theming-support) for more help.

Comment: it would be useful if there would be a switch or other setting from the admin panel. I use dark theme on my laptop, but Django's dark theme is too sharp for me, I like more dimmed themes.

Comment: There might be a solution for you in the upcoming version of Django. Override the admin base template and clear out the `dark-mode-vars` block.

This is currently only possible in the dev version but _might_ be released in 4.0.3

Comment: it would be best if it was customizable for each user :) But I guess that's a bit too much.

Comment: You can create a model for the user's preference and load the css based on it. Refer to https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/dark-and-light-theme-implementation/11035